# Fortran strategy to debug compilation errors

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-warnings, gfortran

I'm having a hard time debugging a compilation error in gfortran. My compiler is:

```
 gfortran -v
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.9.2 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

I can't include the real problem because it's too big. Below I'll discuss a model problem of what's happening:

I have one big module, let's call it ops, that I'd like to break down into several modules (e.g. add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc). To do this, I "use" modules "add" and "subtract" in module "ops", make the routines from "add" and "subtract" public, and then call the routines in "add" and "subtract" from the main program, which only uses "ops".

In this simple example (illustrated below in a simple program), using both modules works fine, and there are no errors. But when I do this with my big program, I get an error when trying to use the "subtract" module (I've also included what I mean in the program comments).

Here's the sample of the scenario:

```
  module add_mod
  private
  public :: add
  interface add;     module procedure add1;    end interface
  contains
  subroutine add1(a,b,c)
    integer,intent(inout) :: a
    integer,intent(in) :: b,c
    a = b + c
  end subroutine
  end module

  module subtract_mod
  private
  public :: subtract
  interface subtract;     module procedure subtract1;    end interface
  contains
  subroutine subtract1(a,b,c)
    integer,intent(inout) :: a
    integer,intent(in) :: b,c
    a = b - c
  end subroutine
  end module

  module ops
  use add_mod
  ! use subtract_mod ! Removing comment causes error...
  private
  public :: init
  public :: add
  ! public :: subtract ! Removing comment causes error...
  contains 
  subroutine init(a,b,c)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(inout) :: a,b,c
    a = 0; b = 0; c = 0
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use ops
  implicit none
  integer :: a,b,c
  b = 1; c = 1
  call add(a,b,c)
  write(*,*) 'a,b,c = ',a,b,c
  ! call subtract(a,b,c) ! want to call...
  write(*,*) 'a,b,c = ',a,b,c
end program
```

The error that I'm getting (in terms of the simplified example) is:

```
\add.o 
\subtract.o 
\subs.o 
\main.o
gfortran: error: main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The error from my big example looks like

```
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\obj\parametricStudy.o
gfortran: error: C:\\Users\\charl\\Documnts\\obj\parametricStudy.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\MOONS] Error 1
```

Where "parametricStudy" is the main program and "MOONS" is the name of the target/executable.

This really does not look like an error in terms of finding the executable, it looks like the executable is not made because of some other issue, but I don't have enough information to find out why. I've tried including all of the debugging flags I can think of:

```
fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -cpp -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -O0 -Og
```

Sorry for the long introduction, but here's my question: How can I debug this? I'm sorry if this was a poorly conveyed question, but I can't re-produce this error in a simple case, so I'm not sure how else to pose the question. Any help on a solution, debugging advice or improving this question is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

After seeing the comment about the compilation error typo, I tried reversing the order of the used modules. That is, now I tried using "subtract" alone, which works fine, but then try using "add" (together) and I get the same error. I'm now beginning to think that this is a compiler bug or something.

UPDATE 2:

I uploaded the code to github. It can be downloaded at

```
 https://github.com/charliekawczynski/MOONS
```

The makefile is in the directory

```
 \MOONS\makefiles\MOONS
```

And the output should show up in out_dir. To compile this, the $TARGET_DIR$ and $SRC_DIR$ must be defined. Please note that right now it is defined with the variable $USER$.

After changing the directory, I see a different misspelling (which seems to change when I make small changes in the code, e.g. removing some warnings related to unused variables).

UPDATE 3:

I've been removing more warnings related to un-used routines and variables, and now I see that the error still exists, but (as far as I see) there is no typo. Here is the new output:

```
gfortran -o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\MOONS -J"
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\mod" -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -cpp -D_DOUBLE_PRECISION_ -D_FFT_RADIX2_ -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -O0 -Og -D_DEBUG_DEL_ -D_DEBUG_INTERP_ -D_DEBUG_APPLYBCS_ 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\IO_tools.o 
...
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\init_Ufield.o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\init_Pfield.o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\energySolver.o 
...
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\MOONS.o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\richardsonExtrapolation.o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\convergenceRate.o 
C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\parametricStudy.o
gfortran: error: C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\obj\init_Pfield.: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\out_dir\\MOONS] Error 1

C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS\makefiles\MOONS>
```

I'm going to try a newer compiler and see if this fixes the problem

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gfortran 5.2.  Can you try a newer version of gfortran?  (and yes, I uncommented all of the lines involving the subtract stuff)

Comment: The spelling of `Documents` in the path reported in the error message of your big example is wrong.  Such a spelling mistake would explain your problems.

Comment: @casey, Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce a small example that does *not* work. I suppose I could try a newer version of gfortran though and see if the problem persists. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Charlie See the comment after my first one. You just might have a typo in a path in your makefile. Check that first.

Comment: @IanH, WOW, I thought that I copied that incorrectly, but I see that "documents" is spelled incorrectly in my CMD. Any idea why this might be the case? I'm using the same make file, the only difference is that I'm adding a file to compile in the make file. Is there a limit on the number of allowable compiled files or something? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: Can you give us the exact compiler line, or the `Makefile` if you're using make?

Comment: I'd be searching all files that might be relevant to the build for that misspelt word.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the problem is related to a typo in the makefile... Would it help if I include a link to the git repo? I need to commit some changes, then I'll push it to got tomorrow morning and post a link here

Comment: *I have a hard time believing that the problem is related to a typo in the makefile*  I don't !  Nor, it would seem, do others who have commented here.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I guess I meant that there isn't a typo in the makefile but in the output to make, I checked, and the makefile uses the correct path, but the output is misspelled..

Comment: I was able to compile the the code I uploaded to github (which currently does not compile) using a different compiler: gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC).